# How to remove/Delete the effect of UNIQUE KEY from TABLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have UNIQUE KEY attribute on my Table. For my project I deleted that UNIQUE KEY from table , but when try to enter data it still giving the error of UNIQUE KEY VIOLATION.

**Already done**

1. to check to commit the database .
2. to refreshed the entire database.
3. to find that CONSTRAINT on schema.

   `SELECT DISTINCT table_name
   FROM all_indexes
   WHERE index_name = 'CONSTRAINT_NAME';`

The above query returns no data (Constraint not found).

I want my data duplicate for one employee without **UNIQUE KEY VIOLATION ERROR**

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message? Doesn't it contain the name of the violated UK?

Comment: Yes it contain the violated unique key name of that UNIQUE KEY which i have already deleted from my table .

Comment: Even I have tried to `Disable all the constraints` on that table but still not working

Comment: do you have trigger applied or sequence on that table ?

Comment: please check the table i am sure you have index on that table or some constraints or u have primary key

Comment: `ALTER TABLE doctor_share_detail DROP UNIQUE (emp_id, service_id)` this query returns `ORA-02442: Cannot drop nonexistent unique key `

Comment: run this and tell what you get SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = '<your table name>';

Comment: select column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name = 'I1T';

Comment: select column_name from user_ind_columns where index_name = 'I1T';

Comment: please run the above queries, i am sure you will find something...maybe your unique index was created before the constraint was created:

Comment: sorry this query return the problem **select column_name from user_ind_columns where index_name = 'EMPID_SERID_UK'; ** please let me know how to delete them now

Comment: the above query return both unique columns names `emp id , service_id`

Comment: is my index name is same as my contraint name i have tried this but having error that `DROP INDEX '<EMPID_SERID_UK>'`

Comment: no your index name is not same as your constraint name ..thats why i suggested two separate queries for dropping indexes and constraints...remove <> and run like this DROP INDEX  'EMPID_SERID_UK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some of the queries you can run and check if there is specified index, constraints exist on the table and once you find you can simply drop it. Maybe your unique index was created before the constraint was created:

```
SELECT * FROM user_cons_columns WHERE table_name = '<your table name>';

select column_name from user_ind_columns where index_name = '<index_name>';

select column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name = '<index_name>';
```

Use below command for dropping index:

```
   DROP INDEX index_name;
```

Use below command for dropping constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> 
    DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR] If you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` without a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` then you will get the same error message. You need to make sure you have dropped both the index and the constraint.

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id NUMBER );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_data__id__u ON test_data ( id );
ALTER TABLE test_data ADD CONSTRAINT test_data__id__u UNIQUE ( id );

INSERT INTO test_data ( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO test_data ( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Will insert one row and will give `ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_ALGCPMTPWFJZCXIPXNLR.TEST_DATA__ID__U) violated` for the second.

If you do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DATA';
SELECT * FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DATA';
```

Then it will show there is an index and a constraint on the table.

Then if you drop the constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test_data DROP CONSTRAINT test_data__id__u;
```

and try to do:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_data ( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Then you will get:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_ALGCPMTPWFJZCXIPXNLR.TEST_DATA__ID__U) violated
```

If you look at the indexes and constraints again:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DATA';
SELECT * FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DATA';
```

Then it will show no constraints but the index is still there. You need to make sure the unique index has been dropped too.

```sql
DROP INDEX test_data__id__u;
INSERT INTO test_data ( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Will then insert the row.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c24ca99741d9d6f88eea68b1ef8edf34)*